# Canonical Q&A for "how to change keybindings?"

Tags: discussion

We get a steady drip of questions, usually by new users, asking
how to bind keys in various modes.  These questions mostly take
the same basic form of "how do I change the keybindings in *mode
X*/*evil*/*spacemacs*/*whatever*?"

**Do we have a canonical Q&A to which we can direct people for
these sorts of questions?** It would be a lot easier than linking
to the manual or various tutorials about keybindings for the
umpteenth time.

Comment: It's not about being easier for us. Pointing to the manuals helps users ask Emacs - in this case, node [Key Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html), and its subnodes, particularly [Rebinding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rebinding.html) and [Init Rebinding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html). SE is not a manual and should not be organized like one: (1) general Q about key binding (2) Q about menu-item binding (3) Q about disabling bindings (3) Q about binding in a keymap,...

Comment: @Drew: agreed, but it would be nice to have at least a semi-canonical question that gives a quick answer and links to the manual on the nodes you cited.

Comment: Go for it. I think that kinda happens organically, by users posing specific questions and by closing duplicates. But a well-phrased Q and its A wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Drew Also, the manual covers only built-in methods (e.g. not the `bind-key` package).

Comment: @T.Verron: Sure, but a *canonical* Q and its A should probably start with (and maybe be limited to?) what's available with distributed Emacs. And it should prioritize helping people learn to *ask Emacs* itself.